# Unable to change font in Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I am using Vue 3 with Vuetify 3 and so far I can't manage to change the font from Roboto to Lato.

I am a beginner in SCSS, but I have created a file called `/scss/main.scss`:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400&display=swap');
$body-font-family: 'Lato';
```

which I import in `main.js`:

```
...
import '../scss/main.scss'
...
```

and then inside `App.vue` I have:

```
#app {
  font-family: $body-font-family, sans-serif !important;
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Could you re-produce your problem on https://stackblitz.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that importing the scss into main.js is doing anything. Instead import it in the style tag of your App.vue.

Try the following in App.vue instead;

```
<template>
...
</template>

<style lang="scss">
@import("path to your scss/main.scss file")

#app {
    font-family: $body-font-family, sans-serif !important;
}
</style>
```